# Git alias command with bash script egrep produces different results

Tags: regex, git, bash, grep

Here's an example of pretty basic shell alias in git

```
[alias]
    em = "!git branch --merged | egrep -v '\\*\\|master' | xargs -L 1 -n 1 echo"
```

It echos the branches that are already merged exluding the master branch (and the current branch you're on). Pretty simple. However the results are different when running this alias and just the script. Example:

```
will ~/example master 
$ git branch --merged | egrep -v '\\*\\|master' | xargs -L 1 -n 1 echo
feature
will ~/example master 
$ git em
feature
*
master
```

For some reason it's like `egrep` clause isn't even run. In fact (since I'm OS X) it's almost like it ran the `grep` command instead! Like this: (note the `grep` vs `egrep`)

```
will ~/example master 
$ git branch --merged | grep -v '\\*\\|master' | xargs -L 1 -n 1 echo
feature
*
master
```

Has anybody come across this before?

I've read up on these SO questions and they aren't dealing with the same thing I am. The top one is the closest, but has to do with from where shell command alias are run (the toplevel of the repo).

[Why does running command as git alias gives different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832799/why-does-running-command-as-git-alias-gives-different-results)

[Bash script produces different result when executed from shell prompt than executed by cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912018/bash-script-produces-different-result-when-executed-from-shell-prompt-than-execu)

Comment: Unrelated, but `-L` and `-n` are mutually exclusive options for `xargs`; only the last one is used.

Comment: True! except in Legacy mode:

"LEGACY DESCRIPTION
     In legacy mode, the -L option treats all newlines as end-of-line, regardless of whether the line is empty or ends with a space.  In addition, the -L and -n options are not mutually-exclusive."

[man pages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xargs.1.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the alias definition undergoes some amount of shell processing (or at least backslash processing) before it is defined. Add *another* set of escaped backslashes to the alias.

```
[alias]
  em = "!git branch --merged | egrep -v '\\\\*\\\\|master' | xargs -L 1 -n 1 echo"
```

Comment: Thanks! I also found that removing the scond backslashes worked:

`\\*|master`